# Does the improved usability of making account creation in checkout optional apply to subscription service e-commerce?

Tags: usability, e-commerce, checkout

Making account creation a requirement for e-commerce checkout experiences has been shown to creation friction that unnecessarily slows users to completing a purchase.

Does this apply to purchasing software products, specifically subscription-based ones, that require setting up an account to use them?

My argument has been that any extra fields slow down checkout and the one for password is a high conversion risk. Engineers have pointed to some competitors and other subscription services which require account set up to make a purchase.

I assume this is irrelevant to the issue at hand and just because a competitor made a trade-off for reasons we don't know, that doesn't invalidate usability research proving otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

> ...any extra fields slow down checkout...password

Bring the customer through payment process with only what is necessary for that, along with either a phone or email verification.

Once payment is complete give them the option to configure their account. Let them know they can always do so later using their phone or email. At the same time send them a SMS or email with instructions how to configure their account.

Until then their phone or email acts as their "password".